# Problems with clouds building P2P network using PNRP in .Net

Tags: network-programming, p2p, netsh, pnrp

I am developing P2P application in .Net using PNRP
protocol. I have already check tons of materials concerning PRNP and
P2P (SO, Microsoft blog etc). But still cant solve the issues with
clouds. And can`t find exact step -by-step instruction for
proper setting up Clouds and peer name resolving. Everything works
perfectly on local machine (registering and resolving names are ok). 
But cloud states for Global and Local always Alone (if i make some
changes sometimes turns to virtual and synchronizing but ended up as Alone). And as result peer names registered on one machine is not
visible on other machine in local network. Ipv6 is supported. Teredo
seems to be working (otherwise global cloud didn't appear):

> ```
>     Scope  Id     Addr   State             Name
>     -----  -----  -----  ----------------  -----
>         3      9      1  Alone            LinkLocal_ff00::%9/8
>         3      5      1  Virtual          LinkLocal_ff00::%5/8
>         1      0      1  Alone            Global_
> ```

The actions I tried (Win 10 + Win 7):

• disabled firewall for all networks.
• turned on (state: running) and set to Automatic:

```
    ○ DNS Client    
    ○ Function Discovery Resource Publication   
    ○ Function Discovery Provider Host  
    ○ SSDP Discovery    
    ○ UPnP Device Host  
    ○ Peer Name Resolution Protocol 
    ○ Peer Networking Grouping      
    ○ Peer Networking Identity Manager  
    ○ PNRP Machine Name Publication Service
```

• made this actions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349394(v=ws.10).aspxLocal

• read and post the same on this blog:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/p2p/2007/07/24/pnrp-debugging-guide-part-1/

• went to Group Policy Editor -->    Administrative Templates --> Microsoft Peer-to-Peer Networking Services --> Global Clouds:

```
    ○ Turn Off Multicast Bootstrap --> disabled     
    ○ Turn Off PNRP cloud creation --> disabled     
    ○ Set PNRP cloud to resolve only --> disabled   
    ○ Set the Seed Server --> Enabled (leaved empty) and for Linc Local --> Not configured.
```

But still can`t see registered names of other machines in local
network and resolve peer names. All cloud states are Alone.  Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance,

P.S.  Ping seed Global_failed, but should not affect the local Cloud?

P.P.S. Ports 3450 and 1900 are opend and added as a rule for Firewall.

Comment: Do you have an IPv6 address (not an fe80 or other link-local address)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Yes I do, starts with 2001:... and linklocal as well (fe80).

Comment: P.S. But it appears on( cmd-->ipconfig):  Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11

Comment: 2001 is a Teredo address I think, which can sometimes have issues connecting to other IPv6 addresses. Can you set up a 6to4 Tunnel through something like tunnelbroker.net ?

Comment: @MatthewSteeples sorry for not replaying. Anyway thank you for the advises. For that time I 
 gave up with that idea. Turned into using WCF and not P2P. But l keep it here in case somebody need it.